# Does creativity have a neurological basis independent of the art form used to express it?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, creativity

The arts provide a medium for creativity, and while some ideas might be easily expressed in various forms of art, some might not be (for example, a sculptor might be able to express the same idea in painting, or perhaps in a short story, but a piano would probably not be as suitable).

So my question is: Does creativity have a noteworthy underlying neurological basis which is independent of the art form one uses to express it?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question (or its point). Could you elaborate?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you referring to creativity as something distinct from ability? For example, someone can be skilled at drawing, but not necessarily creative (in the sense of originality).

Comment: @JeromyAnglim Yes.

Comment: I see two questions here. 1. Can an individual be exceptionally talented in more then one art-form. 2. Can someone who is multi-talented, express the same idea in more than one form. I think the answer to question 1 would make a good topic for research. However I can give a good example from my own experience. My ex-brother-in-law, when I knew him, was a professional sculptor with an exceptional talent for jazz and classical piano. I've just looked him up online and he now makes his living teaching music. 2. It's not clear to me that this question is answerable.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Not necessarily "the same idea". I think I figured out how to explain it better, although I have some reservations, I'll edit the question anyway :P